# Can't move custom symbol in EAGLE

Tags: eaglecad

[image]I made a custom EAGLE Part and it shows up at the board and schematic alright. But when I try to move the symbol in the schematic I am unable to select it. EAGLE keeps saying ´Group is empty!`. Any ideas?

Comment: A picture might help? Maybe the 0, 0 reference point for the object is displaced by such a distance that you can't see it. You need to move an object by clicking close to that reference point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I solved it. The red cross on the right side has to be selected, too.